# TSQL Howto get count of unique users?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is really dumb question but still my head cannot work it out.
I have a table with Orders, each order has userID in it. User can have unlimited amount of Orders. How do i make count of unique userIDs ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can;

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userID) 
FROM Tbl
```

You can give the count column a name by aliasing it:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userID)  NumberOfDistinctUsers
FROM Tbl
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select count(*) from
(select distinct userid form ordertable) d
```